# WebGL: How to get colour in fragment shader to change over time?

Tags: webgl

I'm rather new with webgl: I was wondering how I would go about configuring / setting up the fragment shader so that it would change the colour based on how much time has currently passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the GLSL (Shader code) part is unclear, it's probably best to start out by looking at examples and experimenting in the [GLSL Sandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/) or [Shader Toy](https://www.shadertoy.com/).

It's basically just setting the output of the Shader, `gl_FragColor` to a value depending on a uniform variable (uniform means the same for all processed fragments).

Uniform values can be set from javascript by first retrieving the location of your uniform variable and then setting it to a value, every time time you want to change it (for you it would be every time you draw a frame). The example assumes you already have a compiled and linked webgl program.

```
var program = yourProgram;
var uniformNameInShader = "time";
var location = gl.getUniformLocation( program, uniformNameInShader );

function drawLoop ( ) {
    gl.uniform1i( location, Date.now() );
    render();
}
```

But honestly, you may want to [learn](http://learningwebgl.com/) the [fundamentals](http://webglfundamentals.org) from a [tutorial](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page), because... you know ... research effort and stuff ...

Comment: I try but i got : GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniform1i: wrong uniform function for type , I defined in shader :  uniform float time;  ?!